# Disable iPhone 1.8 GHz radio transmitter?

Tags: iphone, wifi-calling

Is it possible to turn off the 1.8 GHz transmitter on an iPhone via software?

I would like to use WiFi calling only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my iPhone transmitting in airplane mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333648/why-is-my-iphone-transmitting-in-airplane-mode)

Comment: Geremia, you have already effectively asked this question within the last 30 minutes, please could you edit your other post and delete this.

Comment: @unknowndomain No, that question is about airplane mode and how Apple defines it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apple doesn’t allow control over specific radio frequencies. You could jailbreak and try installing / modifying the baseband software or avail yourself of the normal controls to turn on or off WiFi, cellular data, [airplane mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/333648/why-is-my-iphone-transmitting-in-airplane-mode) and Bluetooth. Note, turning many of these off doesn’t disable the radio, but disassociates them from the active connections. Based on what you intend to do, that might suffice.

Keep in mind, you don’t need a SIM or even a registered phone to dial 911 (in the USA and other emergency numbers globally) so the radios stay running independent of the cellular data and service working.

Comment: So you can do a "soft block" of RF, then, on a jail-broken iPhone

Comment: Doesn't removing a SIM card also disable the cellular transmitter?

Comment: I think it changes what information gets sent, but the baseband functions to talk with cell towers and dial 911 even without a SIM. I think the radio is enabled but the cellular carriers shun it for everything except emergency transmissions. I’m confident the radio still talks but we’d need a RF engineer to confirm.

Comment: I think you're right, because 911 calls still are allowed.